# Index invalid or out of range in laravel

Tags: laravel

i used to https://www.simplesoftware.io/#/docs/simple-qrcode to create qr code .  when i use xampp server it works perfectly. But when i move project to server it works sometimes but sometimes it shows this error.

Index invalid or out of range

this is my qr generating code

```
    <div class="text-center ml-1">
    {!! QrCode::size(65)->generate($customer_details); !!}
    </div>
```

is that library issue?

Comment: Do you have the same PHP version on local and on server?

Comment: yes. Both have php version 8.1.

Comment: Can you dump your customer details right above your failing code? Maybe there is something with that content which causes an out of range issue?